# How to install latest version of Tiled Editor on Linux Mint?

Tags: apt, ppa

Having trouble installing latest version of Tiled Editor from console. I need the latest updates for my project.  Adding the PPA is not giving me the latest version of the software.  Running the program says I am on version 0.9.1 which is several years old.  Latest Release 0.15.1.

Added the PPA as described here: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware

Tiled Package page: *Can not post 2nd link*. Google Tiled Map Editor > Click on Downloads link > Click on Unbuntu button > Takes you to the page with the PPA and package information.

**PPA**

> ppa:mapeditor.org/tiled

**Commands ran:**

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapeditor.org/tiled
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install tiled

**Command 1 output:**

> Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options
>   --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.dZ9qFucBve --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring
>   /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/steam.gpg --keyserver
>   hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 9F7F5BAF gpg: requesting key
>   9F7F5BAF from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com gpg: key 9F7F5BAF:
>   public key "Launchpad PPA for mapeditor.org" imported gpg: Total
>   number processed: 1 gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

**Command 2 output:**

> ...SNIP... 
>   Fetched 2,162 kB in 9s (237 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done

**Commad 3 output:**

> ...SNIP... 
>   Setting up tiled (0.9.1-1) ...

**Errors:**
none

**OS:**
Linux Mint 17.3 'Rosa' - Cinnamon 64-bit

Comment: Repost from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/727871/how-to-install-latest-version-of-tiled-editor-on-ubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately, that PPA seems very old and out of date. That version doesn't even seem to be able to load many common image formats. The tileset image selector dialog can't detect jpg/png/gif/tif images on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved in a comment on this page by dadexix86.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/727871/how-to-install-latest-version-of-tiled-editor-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1078796_727871

**Quote:**

> Tried right now on Wily and it works version 0.15.1 . The package name
>   in the ppa is tiled-daily, while tiled is the one in the standard
>   Ubuntu repo (don't know how it is on Mint, thuogh) – dadexix86

**Fix:**

Instead of doing:
sudo apt-get install tiled

This worked to get the daily version (latest version):
sudo apt-get install tiled-daily

Comment: Looks like that package has been removed. `E: Unable to locate package tiled-daily`